# Postgres OFFSET the results of subqueries group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im calculating weekly score for game where certain weeks there are bonuses, and when totaling your score the lowest two scores are dropped.

| id | name | week | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Player A | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | Player A | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | Player A | 3 | 30 |
| 4 | Player A | 4 | 40 |
| 5 | Player B | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | Player B | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | Player B | 3 | 15 |
| 8 | Player B | 4 | 20 |

Let's say in week 2 your score should be doubled,

So A's scores should be  [10,40,30,40] and B [5,20,15,20]

With the rules of removing the two lowest scores

A [40,40] total 80
B [20,20] total 40

If I run this this query

```
select name, sum(special_scores) as total_score
from(
select 
    name,
    case 
        when week = 2 then score * 2
        else score
    end special_scores
    from public.standings
    where name = 'Player A'
    order by special_scores 
    offset 2
) s
group by name
order by total_score desc;
```

I see the expected result of totaling the score column and omitting the last two results, so I believe my sub query is correct.

However if I remove the where clause from the subquery

```
select name, sum(special_scores) as total_score from (
select name, case 
        when week = 2 then score * 2
        else score
    end special_scores from public.standings
order by special_scores
offset 2
) s
group by name
order by total_score desc
```

The table will populate but will not omit the two lowest scores

So I'm getting something like

| name. | total_score |
| --- | --- |
| Player A | 120 |
| Player B | 60 |

Could someone help as to why the offset in the second query is not removing the scores before totaling?

Comment: What if week 2 is one of the lowest scoring weeks?  Your explanation is not complete.

Comment: You can use `row_number()`  window function to number rows within every `name`  separately.

Answer (score 0):

Brake the problem into subproblems.

First create a subquery that computes the actual scores (when they have to be doubled). keep id, week and actual score.

THen use a window function (row_number()) to drop the bottom two scores.

Then sum the results by id.

Finally, join the id to this result table to get the player name too.